# Calculus physics

Tags: calculus, physics

1. A particle moves according to the law of motion,  $s= t^3 -12t^2 +36$, $t$ greater than or equal to $0$ . 
   where ‘$t$’ is measure in seconds and  $s$ is measured in metres.

a)  Find the velocity of the partice after ‘$t$’ seconds.

b)  What is the velocity after $4$ seconds?

c)  What is the particle at rest?

d)  When is the particle moving forward?

e)  Find the total distance travelled by the particle during the first $8$ seconds.

Draw a diagram to illustrate the motion of the particle.  where ‘$t$’ is measure in seconds and  is measured in metres.

Comment: This is not a '' do my homework'' site. Where is your attempt?

Comment: @Deepak  
This is a question in my book that I can not understand, not for homework, i need to understand this in order to do my assignment which we are being given next week so excuse you

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is homework. "This question does not show any research effort." It is frowned upon here to copy and paste questions.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:

a. $v(t) = s'(t) = 3t^2 - 24t$

b. $v(4) = ....$

c. $v(t) = 0 \implies 3t^2 - 24t = 3t(t-8) = 0\implies t = ...$

d. The moving forward means $v \ge 0$. Thus solve: $3t(t-8) \ge 0 \implies t \ge 8$.

e. Total Distance $ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^8 (3t^2 - 24t) dt = ....$

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Truly appreicate it, you're the best!! :D